# Segmentation fault convert in binary

Tags: c, pointers

I'm trying to get work this program but I'm failing. I don't know where I'm wrong.
I get segmentation fault. It's probably the error is due to a pointer that doesn't work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void ConvertBin(int n, int *ris,int *bit);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    int n;
    int ris[20];
    int bit;

    printf("Insert num: "); scanf("%d", &n);

    ConvertBin(n,ris,&bit);

    for (int i=bit; i!=0; i--) 
    {
        printf("%d", *(ris+i));
    }   

    return 0;
}

void ConvertBin(int n, int *ris, int *bit)
{
    int i = 0;

    while (n!=0)
    {
        *(ris+i) = n%2;
        n = n/2;
        i++;
    }

    bit = &i;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is in the last line of your function. `bit = &i;` sets `bit` to address of the local variable `i` (the variable ceases to exist after returning from the function). Value of `bit` is not used after that, in fact the last line of the function has no effect at all. And the calling function (`main`) doesn't receive the updated value of its `bit` variable.

You need to write `*bit = i;` instead: this will write value of `i` into the variable pointer to by `bit` (`main`'s `bit` in your case).

Comment: ok now it works but not totally. It is executed but I don't get the result I aspect. For example if I insert the number 3, I will get 15785073521

Comment: That's probably because you have filled `ris[0...bits-1]`, but you are printing `ris[1...bits]`. Try `printf("%d", ris[i-1]);` (or `*(ris+i-1)` if you prefer this form).

Answer (score -1):

The problem is in the variable i, which was one point bigger than it should be.
This should work fine:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void ConvertBin(int n, int *ris,int *bit);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    int n;
    int ris[20];
    int bit;

    printf("Insert num: "); scanf("%d", &n);

    ConvertBin(n,ris,&bit);

    for (int i=bit; i>=0; i--) 
    {
        printf("%d", *(ris+i));
    }   

    return 0;
}

void ConvertBin(int n, int *ris, int *bit)
{
    int i = 0;

    if( !n ){
        *(ris) = 0;
        i++;
    } else{
        i = 0;
        do
        {
            *(ris+i) = n%2;
            n = n/2;
            i++;
        } while (n!=0);
    }
    *bit = i -1;
}
```